# Need string format to display a 'negated' value

Tags: c#, wpf

Is it possible to have such string format for XAML element's Binding that would display a 'negated' decimal in XAML element?
Like '12.04' should be displayed as '-12.04' and '-4.57' as '4.57'. Multiplying by -1, or using Converter won't work for my task - I need exactly a string format

Comment: why can't you use a converter? Can you use a custom getter that returns the altered property instead of using the original property directly?

Comment: Because its using some custom control, which source code I don't have, and which error I can't figure/fix using conventional methods

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In StringFormat for a decimal number binding, you can supply formatting for the positive, and the negative value. The first one, separated with a semicolon, is the positive, the second one the negative. If, instead of putting the negative sign on the right side, you put it on the left side, it is only going to be used for positive numbers.

```
{Binding SomeValue, StringFormat=-0.##;0.##}
```

Comment: The syntax is wrong, but it is close to what I think the answer should be `StringFormat={}{0:-##.##;##.##}`

Comment: thanks for the proper syntax :) I will add, that the above solution also works on my end

Comment: @JesseGood Actually, what you are claiming is wrong. A StringFormat with a composite format string with format items in curly braces - and hence the need for a leading pair of curly braces in XAML - is just an option. Directly specifying the format, e.g. `StringFormat=F3` for a double value, has always been correct syntax. The example in the answer is spot on, exactly what has been asked for.

Comment: @Clemens Thanks for correcting me, I didn't know you could exclude the curly braces!